# How do I convert bitmap fto FIle in kotlin? I use Fragment

Tags: file, kotlin, bitmap, fragment

This is my code :

```
private val cameraResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && result.data != null) {
                val bitmap = result.data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
                binding.ivProfile.loadImage(bitmap)
            }
        }
```

the result type is bitmap, but the required type that server needed is File. So how can i convert bitmap to File? Thankyou for answering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//create a file to write bitmap data
File f = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);
f.createNewFile();

//Convert bitmap to byte array
Bitmap bitmap = your bitmap;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();

//write the bytes in file
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(bitmapdata);
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```